# Slide in Material UI comes from edge of screen

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

Slide in Material UI transition starts from the edge of the screen, is there any way we can limit the transaction inside card component.
I have posted the code below to emphasize the issue. My objective is to ensure that the transition starts and ends within a component boundary

For example in the code below, I would like the transition to start and end within the card Material UI component

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import { IconButton, CardContent, Slide, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Settings } from "@material-ui/icons"
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'


const styles = {
    card: {
        minWidth: 560,
    },
    cardContent: {
        padding: 8,enter code here
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    },
    smallIcon: {
        width: 36,
        height: 36,
        padding: 0,
    },
    paper: {
        width: "400px",
        height: "320px",
        zIndex: 1,
        position: "absolute",
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        top: "20%",
    }
}

class SimpleCard extends React.Component {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-constructor
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            gearIconClick: ""
        }
    }
    chartFilterSlider = (evt) => {
        debugger
        var clicked = evt.currentTarget.translate
        console.log("clicked", clicked)
        this.setState({
            gearIconClick: clicked
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { classes, } = this.props
        const { gearIconClick } = this.state
        //console.log("gearIconClick",gearIconClick)
        return (
            <Card className={classes.card}>
                <CardContent className={classes.cardContent} >
                    <IconButton className={classes.smallIcon} onClick={this.chartFilterSlider}>
                        <Settings />
                    </IconButton>
                    {gearIconClick ?
                        <Slide direction="left" in={true} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
                            <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paper}>
                                hello
                           </Paper>
                        </Slide>
                        :
                        <div></div>
                    }
                </CardContent>
                {this.props.children}

            </Card>

        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleCard)



Excepted :
 Is there any way we can limit the transaction inside the card component.

Actual output:
Slider in Material UI comes from the edge of the screen
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to `Card`, it should do the job.

Comment: first of all, thank you, you saved my time. and one question can you please explain to me why this works? I mean setting overflow to hidden I think has nothing to do with the transition effect. I just can't understand why this works.

Comment: @amir_70 it doesn't change the transition effect, it still appears from the edge of the screen, but now it is not visible because the container where this transition is defined hides the overflowed content

Answer (score 1):

Also you can check the container prop of Slide component: https://mui.com/components/transitions/#slide-relative-to-a-container